# Add WP editor (WYSIWYG) to WooCommerce settings tab

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, tabs, settings, wysiwyg

I created an dropdown admin field in a custom settings tab of WooCommerce, and I would like to add a WP editor (WYSIWYG) in addition of the dropdown.

How can I do that?

Here is the code I used to create the dropdown in the WC settings tab:

```
    public static function get_settings()
    {
        $product_categories_slug = ['value1', 'value2'];

        $settings = array(
            'section_title' => array(
                'name' => __('VIP settings', 'woocommerce-settings-tab-wc-vip'),
                'type' => 'title',
                'desc' => '',
                'id' => 'wc_settings_tab_wc_vip_section_title'
            ),
            'vip_cat_slug' => array(
                'name' => __('VIP category slug', 'woocommerce-settings-tab-wc-vip'),
                'type' => 'select',
                'options' => $product_categories_slug,
                'desc' => __('Select the category used for VIP', 'woocommerce-settings-tab-wc-vip'),
                'id' => 'vip_cat_slug'
            ),
            'section_end' => array(
                'type' => 'sectionend',
                'id' => 'wc_settings_tab_wc_vip_section_end'
            )
        );

        return apply_filters('wc_settings_tab_wc_vip_settings', $settings);
    }
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

WooCommerce has an action hook for settings fields for custom types, which you can use and write the field output using it.

This is the hook:

```
do_action( 'woocommerce_admin_field_' . $value['type'], $value );
```

You can find this hook on `includes/admin/class-wc-admin-settings.php` file.

so for example, if you define `'type' => 'wp_editor'` then you'll write your action callback function like this:

```
function vh_woocommerce_admin_field_wp_editor_callback( $value ){
    // Write your table row with "wp_editor"
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_admin_field_wp_editor', 'vh_woocommerce_admin_field_wp_editor_callback' );
```